# Trying to make a dynamic web page with PHP code

Tags: php

Hi everyone I'm trying to make a dynamic web page with PHP and I have a problem with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, I think. Every time I press home or about it appends index.php.home or index.php.about to the url. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div style="width:800px; height:auto;">
<nav>
    <a href="index.php/home">home</a>
    <a href="index.php/about">about</a>
</nav>
<?php 
    $path = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],1);
    echo $path;
    if($path==""){
        $path = "home";
    }
    if($path == "home"){    
        ?>
        <h1> Home Page </h1>
        <?php 
    }
    elseif($path == "about"){
        ?>
        <h1> About Page</h1>
        <?php 
    }else{
        ?>
        <h1> Page Not Found </h1>
        <?php 
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Could I have some help with this problem?

Comment: If you run into a problem with some language feature, visit the manual: [`$_SERVER`](http://de.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) - you will find more information and even user-notes that help you to go around the very first corners. What does `'ORIG_PATH_INFO'` give you?

Comment: Try using absolute urls like for example `<a href="/index.php/about">about</a>` or `<a href="/path/to/index.php/about">about</a>`. This will overcome your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use $_GET variable for this. If you have an url like

```
index.php?p=categories&sp=specific_category
```

then you'll have:

```
$_GET['p'] will be categories
$_GET['sp'] will be specific_category
```

so

```
<body> 
<div style="width:800px; height:auto;"> 
<nav> 
<a href="index.php?p=home">home</a> 
<a href="index.php?p=about">about</a> 
</nav> 
<?php  
    if(!isset($_GET['p']) || $_GET['p'] == 'home'){ 
?>
<h1> Home Page </h1>
<?php
    } 
    elseif($_GET['p'] == "about"){ 
?> 
<h1> About Page</h1> 
<?php  
    } else { 
?> 
<h1> Page Not Found </h1> 
<?php  
    } 
?> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a complete path like this

```
<?php
$protocall="http://www.";
$host= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$ext=".com";
$site=$protocall.$host.$ext;

?>

<nav>
    <a href="<?php echo $site; ?>/index.php/home">home</a>
    <a href="<?php echo $site; ?>/index.php/about">about</a>
</nav>
```

define the $site in a global file